# Python arguments contains an object of own class

Tags: python, python-2.7

To try Python I have created the following class:

```
class FunctionParameters(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print 'initialized a functionParameters object'

    #if this method is not static an object (self?) is passed to arguments
    #@staticmethod
    def argumentParams(*arguments):
        print 'argumentParams ---'
        for item in arguments:
            print 'arg ' + str(item)
        print

    #no such object is passed to this method
    def dictionaryparams(paramone,*arguments, **keywords):
        print 'dicitonaryparams ---'
        for item in arguments:
            print item
        print 'I can get more than two params because i use **paramname'
        for item in keywords:
            print item
```

In my main.py I test the class with:

```
import FunctionParameters
paramsTest = FunctionParameters.FunctionParameters()
paramsTest.argumentParams("before", "test", "some arg", "another arg")
paramsTest.dictionaryparams("test" ,"some arg", "another arg", test="some" , bert = "henk")
```

When running main I did notice that the output for argumentParams is:

```
argumentParams ---
arg <FunctionParameters.FunctionParameters object at 0x02D76230>
arg before
arg test
arg some arg
arg another arg
```

and for dictionaryparams

```
dicitonaryparams ---
test
some arg
another arg
I can get more than two params because i use **paramname
test
bert
```

Note the first row of **argumentParams**. However when using @staticmethod for argumentParams the result does not contain that row.  After I found this out I tried to see if there was any difference if I made the **dictionaryparams** function static but for that function it does not pass the object (like the first row of argumentParams) static or not.

So why is there a difference between the arguments in those two functions? Why does **argumentParams(*arguments)** contain a

> FunctionParameters.FunctionParameters object

and why does **dictionaryparams(paramone,*arguments, **keywords)** not contain such an object in the arguments param?

Comment: A python instance method always receives the instance as the first positional argument. This is why the first argument should be called `self` by convension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dictionaryparams` does contain one such parameter object: **`'paramone'`** which you did not output. For instance methods (non-static-, non-class methods), the instance on which the method is called, is automatically passed as the first positional argument:

```
class A(object):
    def a(a1, *args):
        print(a1)  # this s the usual 'self' reference
    def b(*args):
        print(args[0])  # here the first of args is the 'self' reference


x = A()

x.a()
<__main__.A object at 0x00000267AB0C96A0>

x.b()
<__main__.A object at 0x00000267AB0C96A0>
```

These calls are equivalent to:

```
A.a(x)  # x -> a1
<__main__.A object at 0x00000267AB0C96A0>

A.b(x)  # x -> args[0]
<__main__.A object at 0x00000267AB0C96A0>
```

Comment: You don't need to qualify "instance methods" with "normal"; there are three types of *methods*: instance methods, class methods, and static methods.

Comment: @schowaseggl a gotcha I thought you had to use 'self' (exactly type self) and if you used another keyword it did not pass self (for classes where you dont need self).

Comment: @chepner I am aware, that's why I put it in quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

The `self` argument is always passed as the first argument to the method. So, both calls you made will be changed to something like this:

```
paramsTest.argumentParams(paramTest, "before", "test", "some arg", "another arg")
paramsTest.dictionaryparams(paramTest, "test" ,"some arg", "another arg", test="some" , bert = "henk")
```

Now, `paramTest` will be the captured inside the `argumentParams` `*arguments`, but, it will be matched with `paramone` in `dictionaryParams`.

Answer (score 0):

Well in python exists the "self" object as you mentioned.. the self object is kinda like "this" in java but with some differences

in your dictionaryParams function the paramone is acting as the self object since you did not declare it as a `@staticmethod`

I really recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM) to understand it better and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rq8cL2XMM5M)